# How to configure entity encoding in stfalcon/TinymceBundle (Symfony2)?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, tinymce

I am using [stfalcon's TinyMCE Bundle](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle) in my Symfony 2 app. I have my database in UTF8 and I need the TinyMCE to encode entities in ["raw" mode](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding). How do I achieve this with this bundle? Is this possible?

I haven't found any option that could be set in `config.yml` for this bundle.

I can call for a `Init event` function like described [in here](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle#init-event). Maybe I can set this option somehow through this function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution using the `Init event` callback as I mentioned in the question. This workaround should apply for all [TinyMCE configuration options](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration), not only the `entity_encoding`:

In your *config.yml*:

```
stfalcon_tinymce:        
    use_callback_tinymce_init: true
```

And in your **twig template**, where you initialize the TinyMCE:

```
<script>
    function callback_tinymce_init(editor) {
        editor.settings.entity_encoding = 'raw';
    }
</script>
{{ tinymce_init() }}
```